# Solving $f( g(x) f(x) ) = g(x)$,$h(\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}) = g(x)$,$k(\frac{k(x)}{g(x)}) = g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Inspired by functional equations, dynamicals systems and sieve theory I came to the following questions.

Let $x>0$

I was thinking about these individual equations

$$f( g(x) f(x) ) = g(x)$$

$$h(\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}) = g(x)$$

$$k(\frac{k(x)}{g(x)}) = g(x)$$

How to solve such equations ?

I assume solving them is done similar to one another.

To be clear, I am interested in the general case ;

For instance :

$$f( g(x) f(x) ) = g(x)$$

I wonder what if $g(x)$ is given and we want to find some $g(x)$ if it exists ?
Or what if $f(x)$ is given and we want to find some $g(x)$ if it exists ?

Or what if we look for such pairs.

***edit***

I am aware that

$$f( g(x) f(x) ) = g(x)$$

is solved by $f(x) =g(x) = \sqrt x$.

Also $f,g,h $ being constant or moebius transformations is not really what I am looking for.

---